# Can I use one application for multiple telegram bot

Tags: asp.net, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I want to make 2 telegram bots.
Can I use these bots in one project?
Is there a problem with the webhook?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please see this post to edit your question so the community can answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use one page for multiple bots, all you'll have to do is to set the token in base of the bot you want to use, I can show you how to make it in php, but, as I see by your tags, you're using asp.net